# How can I get rough location (country) forAndroid Tablets

Tags: android, geolocation, tablet

I'm looking for a way to know the country-level location.
How to do it on a phone, or devices that have cellular network connectivity or GPS is clear. But what about devices that don't have that?

I know from Google Analytics that Google has that kind of location information,

- How?
- How can I get that information as well? Maybe from the play-store locale or something?
- By "Tablets" I mean devices that have no GPS and no GSM / cellular network connection.

10x

Answer (score 1):

Use the WiFi aproximated location. It checks your IP adress and tries to locate it geographically.

please see [this](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/10/14/a-good-look-at-android-location-data/) or [this.](http://www.idyllramblings.com/2012/03/understanding-android-three-ways-to-find-your-location.html)

a quick summary of the WiFi location method form one of the posted links:

> How it works: Unless you opt out, your phone is periodically sending anonymous data to Google with, among other things, your last known location and any Wi-Fi network you were connected to at the time.  The accumulated data builds on a database begun by traveling Google Streetview cars that recorded Wi-Fi networks available along their routes (the cars no longer do this).

When using this method, your application will ask for the COARSE LOCATION permission on installation.

Comment: Thanks. Let's say a guy buys a tablet and uses it with his home wi-fi. Assume gogle streetview never picked up on his wifi. Will it still give a location, based on the IP address? (neither one of the links you provided says anything about IP)

Comment: @JRun It may, but Im not really sure. Knowing the approximated location of his WiFi is possible, you could ask the ISP if you were the police, for example. Still, since you asked for a location of the country level, Im pretty sure that the device will give you a good estimation on this level regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no clear indication (at least none that I've found) whether or not Google estimates location based on IP as a last resort, my 'getCountry' logic would be as follows:

1. Location location = LocationClient.getLastLocation()
2. If (location == null) location = getLocationByIp()

where getLocationByIP() will use a publicly available, RESTful free web service such as http://freegeoip.net/

Open to suggestions here. If line 2 is redundant I will be happy to drop it.

Cheers
(Y)